# Overriding CSS variables from parent component

Tags: html, css, angularjs

there!

So, I'm trying to do the following: I have a small component in AngularJs that will render a tag-like unit. I am defining general styles inside it, like colors and borders. They are supposed to be the default values. However, I want to outer components to be able to override it by changing the value of the CSS variable. Here's the example:

*tagLike.html*

```css
.tag-like-container {
  --tag-like-color: red;
  
  color: var(--tag-like-color);
 }
```

```html
 <div class="tag-like-container">
    my tag
 </div>
```

And, then, the outer component will call it

*outerComponent*

```css
.outer-container {
  --tag-like-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <tag-like></tag-like>
</div>
```

However, the final value of `--tag-like-color` is *red*, but I want it to be *blue*. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your are changing the color, but you've never applied the actual color value to the `.outer-container`. You need to specify that `.outer-container` should be using the variable for the color.

```css
.outer-container {
    --tag-like-color: blue;
    color: var(--tag-like-color);
 }
```

Comment: But inside of the tagLike component I am explicit saying `color: var(--tag-like-color`...I wanted the statement outside the tagLike component to override the statement inside of it. I think it's actually not possible...

Comment: I found a way of doing this by setting a default value to the var function, like `color: var(--tag-like-color, red)`, but this isn't exactly what I want, since I was looking for declaring all variables in the container of the inner component....

Comment: It's due to the cascading effect of CSS. You define the color for the outer component, then it changes the color once you get to the inner component. Try giving the outer component the !important flag on the color. Although that's still not what you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution! The way is to use 2 variables, like so:

*outerComponent*

```css
.tag-like-override {
  --tag-like-color: blue;
 }
```

```html
<tag-like class="tag-like-override"></tag-like>
```

And, in the innerComponent, using `var(value, fallback)` model, we can define

*innerComponent*

```
--final-tag-color: var(--tag-like-color, red);
color: var(--final-tag-color);
```

This way, if the color is defined by the outer component, the final value will be the one of the override; otherwise, it will be the fallback value, in this case, red.

By doing so, it is possible to create a manifesto of all the overridable styles on the top-most level class of the component, creating a black-box component.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: you simply need to write `color: var(--tag-like-color, red)`, no need for the extra variable

Comment: Hi, there. So, simply writing it as you said would cause some problems. For example, if a component outside of the innerComponent stated that it wants the color to be blue, the final value would that of the innerComponent, red. Having to variables enables for overriding the one inside innerComponent from outside of it. This was the problem in the first place. But thanks for the help, anyways =D